# Not getting cookie value in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, cookies

Here is my code to set cookie

```
 $cookie = array(
         'name'   => 'City',
         'value'  => $city,
         'expire' => 86400 * 30,
         'domain' => '.localhost',
         'path'   => '/',
         'prefix' => 'picker_',
         );
    $this->input->set_cookie($cookie)
```

and i loading cookie helper in constructor of a controller.

my cookie is set form 1 month and i check in browser my cookie is set name 
'City' and  value = '10'. the problem is when i retrieve the value i get the blank page nothing is printing

here the code of fetching  value

```
echo $this->input->cookie('picker_City');
```

i also try var_dump

```
var_dump($this->input->cookie('City', false));
```

it return false

what is the error.

Comment: try with var_dump($this->input->cookie('City', TRUE));

Answer (score 2):

You have to load the helper cookie first before using `set_cookie`

```
$this->load->helper('cookie');
```

and then use `set_cookie`

If you are using cookies very often , its better you load it in the `autoload.php` in the config folder.

in the autoload array

```
$autoload['helper'] = array('cookie');
```

Did you load it?

**NOTE:**

For local testing, leave the `domain` value blank.

```
'domain' => '',
```

Comment: i was loading cookie  helper in constructor of controller